# Application is crashing

Tags: android

I am working in android. i am designing a custom dialog in which there are two buttons one for close and one for paypal. whenever i press paypal button, this program terminated.

this is my code:-

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    Button close;

    String TAG="CustomizeDialog";



    Context customize_dialog;

    CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment;

    public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        /** It will hide the title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        customize_dialog=context;
        setContentView(R.layout.paypal_custom_dialog);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paypal_close);
        text_view_price.setText("Price : "+price_of_song);

        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        if (pp == null) {
            try {
                pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(context, "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
        }




        launchSimplePayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(context,

        PayPal.BUTTON_118x24, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

        LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Paypal_Custom_Dialog_View);


        launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener( this);


        lnr.addView(launchSimplePayment);




        close.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "i am closing tag");
        if (v == close)
            dismiss();
        if(v==launchSimplePayment)
        {
            dismiss();
            PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

            payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("2.25"));

            payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

            payment.setRecipient("kuntal_1316186174_biz@gmail.com");

            payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

            Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,customize_dialog);

            ((Activity) customize_dialog).startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
        }



    }


}
```

please check the code and point out what mistake i have done ?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: There may be a different error, but this line looks strange:   ((Activity) customize_dialog).startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);  try to replace with startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);

Comment: past the stacktrace. why do you call dismiss at the beggining of the block instead at the end?

Comment: yeah i tried this startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1); but this is creating a error that "startActivityForResult method is undefined for customiseDialog"  please help me...

Comment: i called to dismiss first beacause i want to show the paypal fuctionality in the base context not in the custom dialog. so after pressing paypal button custom dialog should remove and paypal website must call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for the problem:-

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "i am closing tag");
        if (v == close)
            dismiss();
        if(v==launchSimplePayment)
        {

```
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

        payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("2.25"));

        payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

        payment.setRecipient("kuntal_1316186174_biz@gmail.com");

        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

        Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,customize_dialog);

        ((Activity) customize_dialog).startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
    }
```